# Is my Code Is correct I want to just getting error in IF condition in mysql. Here my intention is to use IF as a TERNARY Operator in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO time_line( tl_name, tl_dob, tl_message)
select em_first_name, em_DOJ,
IF(CONCAT('Congrats On ', TIMESTAMPDIFF(year, em_DOJ,now()), ' Years 
Completed') ==  0, 'New Joined',
CONCAT('Congrats On ', TIMESTAMPDIFF(year, em_DOJ,now()), ' Years 
Completed'))
from employee_master where MONTH(em_DOJ) = MONTH(NOW()) and DAY(em_DOJ) = 
DAY(NOW());
```

Here my intention is to  Use IF as a Ternary Operator in Mysql If Concat Returns 0 That time "NEW JOINED I WANT TO RETURN" Otherwise Returns actual value

Comment: And what exactly is your problem? Do you get an error, unexpected results or what?

Comment: May be you intend  `IF TIMESTAMPDIFF(year, em_DOJ, now())=0`    ?

Comment: IF should give some result

Comment: select concat('abc',timestampdiff(year,now(),'2017-01-01') ) results in abc0 ,as @etsa suggests you need to test the timestampdiff before concatenating. Also I would do this as a case statement.

Comment: Without IF, this is working like the following code                                                                                INSERT INTO time_line(tl_name, tl_dob, tl_message)
select em_first_name, em_DOB, CONCAT(TIMESTAMPDIFF(year, em_DOB, now()) , ' BIRTH DAY')
From employee_master where MONTH(em_DOB) = MONTH(NOW()) and DAY(em_DOB) = DAY(NOW());

Comment: Your point being?

Comment: Have You understood?